# Does the new Electorate badge include downvotes and votes on CW questions?

Tags: discussion, electorate-badge

The title kinda says it all. With reference to the new [Electorate badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate):

- Do the votes counted for questions include both upvotes *and* downvotes?
- Do votes on Community Wiki questions count in the vote total?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, CW posts count as well. CW posts generally count for everything badge related unless they are specifically excluded in the description.